# How to request another container linked in the same docker compose file

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I need to pass data from one microservice to another microservice. each one is in seperate docker image.
I have linked the container A to container B in docker-compose.yml but I need to request it through an url in my appsetting.json.

```
    containera:
        image: containera
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: containera/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "9102:80"
        links:
            - containerb

    containerb:
        image: containerb
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: containerb/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "9101:80"
```

in my appsetting.json in container A

```
"BaseUrl": "http://*/api/dostuff/"
```

Any idea how to do that please ?

Comment: You should no longer be using the `links` keyword in your compose files. By default, your containers will be able to refer to each other by name.  For example, from within `containera` you can refer to a web service on `containerb` as `http://containerb/` with no additional configuration.

Comment: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes this setup in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

cause of docker-compose create a network for all of the services in the same file you don't have to use links and to connect them together you can use service name as dns name